# How to add dom element in my case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add an additional `<tr>` element when user click an link inside a `td.`

I have something like in html

```
<tr ng-repeat="test in tests">
    <td ng-repeat="item in test">
        <a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>{{item.name}}<a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

so my actually html is like

```
<tr>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>1</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>2</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>3</a></td>
    <td><a item-detailhref='' ng-click='open()'>4</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>5</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>6</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>7</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>8</a></td>
</tr>
…more
```

My goal is to put new new tr tag between two `tr` tag when user click a button so it will be like

```
//click any of link here inside a td, add new tr next to it
<tr>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>1</a></td>  
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>2</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>3</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>4</a></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="4">Newly added</td></tr> <- add one if I click 1,2,3,4
<tr>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>5</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>6</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>7</a></td>
    <td><a item-detail href='' ng-click='open()'>8</a></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="4">Newly added</td></tr> <- add one if I click 5,6,7,8
```

my js

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('itemDetail', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                var html = '<tr><td> newly added </td></tr>'
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    //not sure what to do here. there is no closet method in Jquery lite
                })         
            }
        };
    }
);
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this by using directive. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you just want to add a `tr`, or do you also want to display details about the selected item in that `tr`?

Comment: I need to display details too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to have a scope variable per `test` that holds which `item` was selected. If this variable is set, then show the details `<tr>`. You could set this in the View:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="test in tests" ng-init="selectedItem = null">
    <td ng-repeat="item in test">
        <a href='' ng-click='$parent.selectedItem = item'>{{item.name}}<a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="selectedItem">
    <td colspan="4">Details of: {{selectedItem}}</td>
</tr>
```

(`ng-init` is actually not needed there, but I added it for clarity)

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qIPJmGgoJumf2sdZP8J0?p=preview)

A better approach would probably be to add a property to the `tests` array itself or create a new array to hold the selected item for each test based on the index of the test (to which the item belongs) in the `tests` array.

Comment: what does ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end do? + 1

Comment: It defines the boundaries of what will be repeated. Here you'd need both `<tr>`s to be repeated as a group for each `test`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need directive for this. Dont manipulate html when you dont need - let angular do it for you:

```
  <a href='' ng-click='open($parent.$index)'>{{item.name}}</a>
```

in controller:

```
  $scope.open = function(index) {
    $scope.tests.splice(index + 1, 0, [{name : 'n'}, {name: 'p'}]);
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview